# Quagga between service provider and kvm

Tags: networking

I am running Quagga between me and my service provider; the connection has been working well (Established). M AS number is 203459 and my IP address prefix is 185.133.224.0/24.

How can I use my address on other fake devices (VM), knowing that I have installed KVM or can I use my address on the same device ... I read a lot I could not found answer ?

```
my network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto em1
iface em1 inet manual
bond-master bond0

auto em2
iface em2 inet manual
bond-master bond0

auto bond0
iface bond0 inet static
address 213.163.73.97
netmask 255.255.255.128
broadcast 213.163.73.127
gateway 213.163.73.1
dns-nameserver 8.8.8.8
bond-lacp-rate 4
bond-slaves none
bond-mode 4
bond-miimon 100
bond_downdelay 200
bond_updelay 200
bond-xmit-hash-policy layer3+4
bond-mode 802.3ad

auto bond0:0
iface bond0:0 inet static
        address 185.133.224.1
        netmask 255.255.255.0
```

Answer (score 0):

First, I don't know if you've noticed, but 185.133.224.0/24 is not being announced (or at least it's not reaching routeviews). I can see 185.133.225.0/24 and a few more /24s being announced from your AS, so you are definitely doing something wrong here.

Second, how you forward stuff in your internal network has little to do with BGP, by definition! When you run KVM, or any other kind of virtualization, it appears as if it's running on yet another ethernet segment coming off your machine; `ip link list` should give you all the configured interfaces. Usually the ancillary software that brings up KVM (or xen, or VMWare, or whatever) will also bring up the necessary virtual networks, but it's your responsibility to provide routing and forwarding. Again, BGP has nothing to do with this, it's just local static configuration.